# Only allowing authenticated users to access certain pages in django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to make it so that only a user that is logged can access a page but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my views.py

```
@login_required
def course(request):
    data = Students.objects.all()
    context = {'data', data}
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login/course.html', context)
```

I have also tried to restrict access by doing

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>Course Page!</h1>
{% else %}
    <a href="/">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

The first way I tried in the views.py file always let me see the page and  the second way always only displays the login link. It's probably something small but I can't seem to work it out. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: So to clarify, when you say 'The first way I tried in the views.py file always let me see the page', do you mean it's rendering `login/course.html`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't very clear about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough. If a anonymous user can still access that view function, the user is maybe authenticated.

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def course(request):
    data = Students.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'login/course.html', {'data': data})
```

Are you sure that you are not authenticated? Try deleting cookies for localhost and open the view again.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try passing the user through the response with something like:

```
return render_to_response('login/course.html', {'context': context, 'user': request.user})
```